# Switch statement not receiving parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, switch-statement

I am having a problem with a switch statement. I have simplified a little bit here but my project is a gallery of pictures and when you click on one picture that picture is loaded. The base html is simple:

html:

```
<section id="content">    
    <div id="container">    
        <img src="Images/Image1.jpg" id="#image" class="bigImage" />
        <div id="info">Title1</div>  
    </div> <!-- end of container -->    
</section> <!-- end of content -->
```

the html for the gallery:

```
<section id="content">
<div id="container">
  <div id="gallery" class="sections">
    <img src="Images/Image1.jpg" class="thumbnails">
    <img src="Images/Image2.jpg" class="thumbnails">
    <img src="Images/Image3.jpg" class="thumbnails">
    etc...
  </div>
</div> <!-- end of content -->
</section> <!-- end of container -->
```

The function to do this:

```
$( document ).on('click', '.thumnails', function(e){        
    var imageSource = $(this).attr('src');  
    $( '#container' ).remove();    
    $( '#content').load('index.html' + ' #content', function(){    
        $( '#image' ).attr('src', imageSource);
    }).hide().fadeIn('slow');

});
```

All this works fine. Now I would like to update the content of the #info div that has the title of each picture. For this I create a simple function that contains the switch statement:

```
   function updateInfo(number){
      switch(number) {
        case 1:
          $( '#info').text('Title1');
          break;
        case 2:
          $( '#info').text('Title2');
            break;
        case 3:
          $( '#info').text('Title3');
          break;
        etc...
      }
   }
```

Then I update my original event listener by adding a call to that function like so:

```
$( document ).on('click', '.thumbnails', function(e){  
    var imageSource = $(this).attr('src');   
    $( '#container' ).remove();    
    $( '#content').load('index.html' + ' #content', function(){    
        $( '#image' ).attr('src', imageSource);    
        counter = imageSource.match(/\d+/g);
        updateInfo(counter);    
    }).hide().fadeIn('slow');    
});
```

And this is not working. The image gets updated but the title doesn't and it always shows: Title1.

I have done a bit of testing to see why. I have put an alert() statement inside the updateInfo function like so:

```
function updateInfo(number){
    alert(number);    
    switch(number) {
        case 1:
          $( '#info').text('Title1');
          break;
        case 2:
            $( '#info').text('Title2');
            break;
        case 3:
          $( '#info').text('Title3');
          break;
        etc...
    }
}
```

And that works, which means that when I click on a picture, before showing that picture I get an alert box with the number of the picture I click, so I know the function is getting called and the parameter is being passed. But when I move the alert(number); statement inside one of the case clauses, like so:

```
function updateInfo(number){    
    switch(number) {
        case 1:
          $( '#info').text('Title1');
          break;
        case 2:
            alert(number);
            break;
        case 3:
          $( '#info').text('Title3');
          break;
        etc...
    }
}
```

I don't get an alert box. I am still fairly new to programming so this could be a basic mistake. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`match` returns an array.

Change your code to:

`updateInfo(counter[0]);`

Also, the variable will come out as a string, so you need to wrap your case variables in quotes, e.g.: `case '1':`

```js
function updateInfo(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case "1":
      console.log(1);
      break;
    case "2":
      console.log(2);
      break;
    case "3":
      console.log(3);
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Unrecogised number: ' + number);
      break;
  }
}
var counter = 'Images/Image2.jpg'.match(/\d+/g);
updateInfo(counter[0]); //2
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I've tried both things and they don't fix the problem. I have a call to the same function updateInfo() at another point in my script and it is working there, but when I change it like you say it works in neither

Comment: I've updated my answer with a code example. I recommend adding a `default` case to your switch statement so you can see what `number` you are actually getting.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid conflicts, since the variable number would be a string. change the code by including the case values within quotes shown as below.

```
 function updateInfo(number){
  switch(number) {
    case '1':
      $( '#info').text('Title1');
      break;
    case '2':
      $( '#info').text('Title2');
        break;
    case '3':
      $( '#info').text('Title3');
      break;
    etc...
  }
 }
```